# How to pass basic authentication headers to legacy servlet while using ServletRegistrationBean

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-boot

I have been trying out to migrate a existing legacy application to spring boot application.

I have a legacy servlets which are registering using ServletRegistraionBean,My internal servlets are using basic authentication to validate resturl. How can I add basic auth while registering the servlet.below is my code snippet for registering servlet.

```
@bean
public ServletRegistrationBean discoveryServletRegistration(MappingServlet mappingServlet) {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean( mappingServlet);
    registration.addUrlMappings("/mapmyservletapi/", "/pooledservletapi/");
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: And why would that change... Your servlet is still your servlet...

Comment: Yeah my servlet is still a servlet and could reach from spring boot container as http://localhost:8080/mapmyservlet/api1. but i need to include basic authentication in the request url made and that has to be passed to mapped servlet.